# Azure DevOps Armtemplate Yaml disable/enable job through variable group

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is there a way to enable and disable a job in yaml as a variable? So i can define it in a variable group. Instead of creating a new repo/branch for deployment of armtemplate in azuredevops.

```
steps:
-   task: PublishSymbols@2

  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'

    inputs:
      SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
      PublishSymbols: false
      enabled: "true/false variable"
      continueOnError: true
```

Comment: yes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 3):

As Shayki linked

```
variables:
- group: YourGroupName

steps:
- task: PublishSymbols@2

  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  condition: eq('${{ variables.enabled}}', true)
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
    PublishSymbols: false

    continueOnError: true
```

Asuming that your variable group contains `enabled` variable.

Comment: this syntax worked for me, `and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isMain, 'true'))` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: The syntax in answer is for variables from variable group.

Comment: Sorry for late response. But the solution for me was to define like this when we switched to use variables from yaml file

condition:  eq('${{ parameters.Enabled }}', 'true')

Comment: So you switched to runtime parameters, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.